# How to solve Cauchy-Euler ODE $x^2 y''(x) - 2x y'(x) + 2 y(x) = x \sin x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $x^2 y''(x) - 2x y'(x) + 2 y(x) = x \sin x$. Solving for the homogeneous solution is simple: the characteristic equation results in roots 1 and 2 so we have $y_c = Ax + Bx^2$, which works. Since $y_p = u(x) y_1 + v(x) y_2$ by variation of parameters, the Wronskian is $x^2$, and $u(x) = - \int \frac{x^2 (x \sin x)}{x^2}$ and $v(x) = \int \frac{x (x \sin x)}{x^2}$ we should get $y_p = -x \int x \sin x + x^2 \int \sin x$.

However, this solution doesn't work. Plugging the equation into Wolfram, the particular integral should be $y_p = -x \int \frac{\sin x}{x} + x^2 \int \frac{\cos x}{x} - x\sin x$. I've tried to reverse engineer what the values of $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ but they don't make sense. What is missing here?

Comment: You need to divide out by $x^2$ first. The variation of parameters method works on equations of the form $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=f(x)$, i.e, the $y''$ coefficient needs to be $1$.